# How do P(&sem) and V(&sem) in semaphore affect the code?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I have this main code that executes pthread_create with a function "doit" as one of its parameter. I have three doit functions where each of them has P and V placed differently or doesn't have P and V at all. My question is, how would each of the output differ? More specifically, what would be possible outputs for each of the doit function?

What I know so far is that P(&sem) will turn the sem value into 0 and V will turn the value into 1. However, I'm having a hard time interpreting how it'll affect the code.

What I think so far is that doit function #1 will result in 
1
2
3
as printf and i=i+1 are well secured by P(&sem) and V(&sem).

Also, all the possible outputs with doit function #2 in my opinion are
1, 2, 3///
1, 3, 3///
2, 2, 3///
2, 3, 3///
3, 3, 3. 
please correct me if I'm wrong.

However, I'm really not sure about what would happen with multiple threads when it comes to doit function #3 in terms of possible outputs. I'd appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

```
  sem_t sem;
  /* semaphore */


  int main(){
     int j;
     pthread_t tids[3];
     sem_init(&sem, 0,1);
     for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
        pthread_create(&tids[j], NULL, doit, NULL);
        }
     for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
        pthread_join(&tids[j], NULL);
        }
     return 0;
     }


  doit# 1.
  int i = 0;
  void *doit(void *arg){
     P(&sem);
     i = i + 1;
     printf("%d\n", i);
     V(&sem);
     }


  doit #2.
  int i = 0;
  void *doit(void *arg){
     P(&sem);
     i = i + 1;
     V(&sem);
     printf("%d\n", i);
     }


  doit #3.
  int i = 0;
  void *doit(void *arg){
     i = i + 1;
     printf("%d\n", i);
     }
```

Comment: C does not specify what will be printed in 2 or 3, anything is possible because of a data race. However, there is a write race in 3, which probably means that even more peculiar outcomes could happen in practice than with 2.

Comment: Hence the only function for which we can speak with certainty is the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first program will print

```
1
2
3
```

It is the only program where all accesses to `i` are properly guarded by *P*/*V*.

The **behaviour** of the 2 other programs is **undefined**, because the write in one thread might happen simultaneously with the read in other thread, and according to [C11 5.1.2.4p25](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p25):

> 25. The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

and [C11 5.1.2.4p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.4p4)

> 4. Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

Oftentimes these kinds of assignments ask to find a difference between 2 and 3. They're wrong. From the C perspective you've opened the Pandora's box already and anything is possible.